# Losing Details when reducing to smaller image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, image-quality

I am designing icons and elements from an android game using Photoshop CS4. If I am designing a character (512x512) and reduce its size to fit the game screen, lots of details, shades and effects are not visible clearly. How to over come this and create smaller icon with clear and clear details ?
Any suggestion, ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the game icon and are they variable?

Comment: Mostly it wont vary(no zooming kinda effects)! but all those icons and elements wont be in standard size(different elements with different sizes).

Comment: my ques is far away from that one. I am asking about the elements used in the game screen. When i design those in bigger screen with high res, they looks great, but when resize as per the requirement, they lose their details and clarity.

Comment: You are right - I think I meant to say that the question (http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/11349/why-are-some-details-of-an-icon-fuzzy) is different but the answers may help.

Comment: Thx !! seriously I learnt many things in this discussion !!

Comment: I learnt things from all of your answers, but I can choose only one ! Thanks for your replies !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would convert your layers to one smart object so you can resize it without quality loss. Plus "Unsharp Mask" filter for the smart object.

UPDATE:
You must do all modifications (resize, sharp, effects etc.) before you export the end image. The photoshop smart object can be resized without quality loss. So after you are ready with layout of the icon - just select all layers (with folders if you have some) and add it all to the smart object. After that resize only that object and export it as png of something else

Look at this test picture: a normal layer with "drop shadow" and "stroke" effects and the same layer but converted to the smart object.

[image]

Comment: Thx for your reply. Can u please give me more details on this? after my file is ready i ll save as .png file. Later if i reduce the size its not clear.

Comment: You must do all modifications (resize, sharp, effects etc.) before you export the end image. The photoshop smart object can be resized without quality loss. So after you are ready with layout of the icon - just select all layers (with folders if you have some) and add it all to the smart object. After that resize only that object and export it as png of something else.

Comment: Not sure this really answers the question. While it's true a Smart Object can be scaled up and down without affecting the quality of its content, the exported small icon is going to look much the same as regular artwork downscaled once, and detail will be lost. The comment adds useful info though and I would suggest folding it into the answer.

Comment: @HariharanAnbazhagan: It is *probably* better in most cases to save the source files and re-export the different sizes from the source file rather than resizing a png.

Comment: @horatio Thq, Its better to resize the source file instead of reducing png file !

Comment: @mast0r Thanks for your answer, really helped me a lot !

Answer (score 4):

Converting to a smart object won't change the quality when the image is reduced, it will only allow you to resize the image afterwards back to normal without loss of quality.

Convert to smart object anyway, as it's good practice.

Go to Settings -> General

Change 'Image Interpolation' to 'Bicubic sharper' see if that helps maintain some detail.

Answer (score 4):

Essentially, you have to draw or re-draw your small icon. Ideally you work from a vector based version that you scale down and then tweak the details on pixel-level, but scaling down a rastered version will work, too. Your scaling results will be better, if you scale exactly 50%, 25%, 12.5%, etc, because photoshop has to blur less between pixels. Additionally, you can try applying sharpening filters after the resize to emulate more of the original pixel sharpness.